# Turtle window doesn't close and shows error " terminator " even with 2 lines of code

Tags: python-3.x, oop, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-turtle

I am learning about OOP in python and to be specific about turtle module.
Wrote this code and running it shows error " Terminator " ...hope its not the skynet

```py
timmy = Turtle()
print(timmy)
timmy.shape("turtle")
timmy.color("blue")
```

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminator                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 1 in <cell line: 4>()
      1 from turtle import Turtle,Screen
----> 4 timmy = Turtle()
      5 print(timmy)
      6 timmy.shape("turtle")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/turtle.py:3815, in Turtle.__init__(self, shape, undobuffersize, visible)
   3813 if Turtle._screen is None:
   3814     Turtle._screen = Screen()
-> 3815 RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
   3816                    shape=shape,
   3817                    undobuffersize=undobuffersize,
   3818                    visible=visible)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/turtle.py:2558, in RawTurtle.__init__(self, canvas, shape, undobuffersize, visible)
   2556 self._undobuffersize = undobuffersize
   2557 self.undobuffer = Tbuffer(undobuffersize)
-> 2558 self._update()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/turtle.py:2661, in RawTurtle._update(self)
   2659     return
   2660 elif screen._tracing == 1:
-> 2661     self._update_data()
...
-> 1293     raise Terminator
   1294 if self._tracing > 0:
   1295     self._updatecounter += 1

Terminator:
```

[turtle graphics window which doesn't close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxVB2.png)

[If i re-run the program it runs fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKhB8.png)

```py
from turtle import Turtle,Screen


timmy = Turtle()
print(timmy)
timmy.shape("turtle")
timmy.color("blue")

timmy.forward(100)
my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.bgcolor("coral")
my_screen.exitonclick()
```

Error message:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminator                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 1 in <cell line: 4>()
      1 from turtle import Turtle,Screen
----> 4 timmy = Turtle()
      5 print(timmy)
      6 timmy.shape("turtle")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/turtle.py:3815, in Turtle.__init__(self, shape, undobuffersize, visible)
   3813 if Turtle._screen is None:
   3814     Turtle._screen = Screen()
-> 3815 RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
   3816                    shape=shape,
   3817                    undobuffersize=undobuffersize,
   3818                    visible=visible)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/turtle.py:2558, in RawTurtle.__init__(self, canvas, shape, undobuffersize, visible)
   2556 self._undobuffersize = undobuffersize
   2557 self.undobuffer = Tbuffer(undobuffersize)
-> 2558 self._update()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/turtle.py:2661, in RawTurtle._update(self)
   2659     return
   2660 elif screen._tracing == 1:
-> 2661     self._update_data()
...
-> 1293     raise Terminator
   1294 if self._tracing > 0:
   1295     self._updatecounter += 1

Terminator:
```

Again re-running gives the desired output

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: made changes as instructed

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code,  Although I might have expressed it differently:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.bgcolor("coral")

timmy = Turtle()
timmy.shape("turtle")
timmy.color("blue")

timmy.forward(100)

my_screen.exitonclick()
```

You need to look outside your code for the problem.  In this case, the Anaconda environment.  Try it outside that environment to convince yourself the code works.

Depending on how Anaconda tries to rerun it, there might be a `Terminator` error as once the turtle environment shuts down after the `exitonclick()` it cannot be restarted.  The program has to be rerun anew, in a clean image.

Comment: Tried it in Global env too but still shows problem and upon re running once or twice runs fine.
in the 1st code block there is no `exitonclick()` still i am having the problem.